# comparing data between txt and csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files where I want to compare value of firstname, lastname and account_id between the two files in Python.
Content of the two files are as below

**users.csv contains below content where column names are first_name,last_name,id respectively**

```
Test1,Last1,1101011
Test2,Last2,1231231
```

**user1.txt contains**

```
[{'firstname': 'Test1',
  'time_utc': 1672889600.0,
  'lastname': 'Last1',
  'name': 'Test Last1',
  'account_id': 1101011},
 {'firstname': 'Test2',
  'time_utc': None,
  'lastname': 'Last2',
  'name': 'Test2 Last2',
  'account_id': 1231231}]
```

I tried with below code but it returns false result and returns all the users even though they are present in both the files.

```
import csv

with open ("users.csv", 'r') as read_csv:
    f = csv.reader(read_csv)
    with open ("user1.txt", 'r') as file:
        x = file.readlines()
        print (x)
        for row in f:
            print(row)
            if row not in x:
                print (row)
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* thing this does that you didn't expect?

Comment: It returns data even if it's present in the file  ["[{'firstname': 'Test1',\n", "  'time_utc': 1672889600.0,\n", "  'lastname': 'Last1',\n", "  'name': 'Test Last1',\n", "  'account_id': 1101011}
,\n", " {'firstname': 'Test2',\n", "  'time_utc': None,\n", "  'lastname': 'Last2',\n", "  'name': 'Test2 Last2',\n", "  'account_id_id': 1231231
}]"]
['Test1', 'Last1', '1101011']
['Test1', 'Last1', '1101011']
['Test2', 'Last2', '1231231']
['Test2', 'Last2', '1231231']

Comment: That isn't the *first* thing, its *all* the things.

Comment: Check if you don't actually want to see the last `print(row)` only. Remove the other print statements...

Comment: @Andreas I get ['Test1', 'Last1', '1101011']
['Test2', 'Last2', '1231231'] even if data is present in txt file

Comment: `x` is a list of strings, each containing one line from the file "user1.txt". `row` holds columns from one line in "users.csv" (["Test1", "Last1", "1101011"] for example). Your code tries a comparison that will not succeed: `["Test1", "Last1", "1101011"] in x`.